# Ktor client MockEngine not resolved in android

Tags: android, kotlin, ktor

I've added the dependency for *[Ktor client mock](https://ktor.io/clients/http-client/testing.html)*

```
testImplementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-mock:$ktor_version"
```

But still the MockEngine is not resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a multi-platform module with no *actual* implementations.
to use in platform modules, jvm in the case of android a corresponding dependency should be used. In this case you should use instead:

```
testImplementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-mock-jvm:$ktor_version"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have written an article about Ktor and Ktor client mock where you can review a working example.

https://medium.com/@xurxodev/how-to-create-a-rest-api-client-and-its-integration-tests-in-kotlin-multiplatform-d76c9a1be348

The source code is on this GitHub repository
https://github.com/xurxodev/integration-testing-kotlin-multiplatform-kata

Review it and let me know if you have some doubts